# How to encode multibyte filenames in PHP and decode them in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, encoding

Here is some example of file names:

```
漢語.jpg (Chinese)
Федерация.jpg (Russian)
AbÇöişÜĞ.jpg (Turkish, ISO-8859-9)
...
```

I have tried `rawurlencode(mb_convert_encoding($file, "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($file)))` but this is not working, all Chinese and Russian characters printed as %3F(regular question mark) and all Turkish characters are removed.

I am testing on Windows, PHP 5.3.

Only solution i found is to enter encoding explicitly: `rawurlencode(mb_convert_encoding($file, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-9"))` This works only for Turkish characters.

By the way, `mb_detect_encoding($file)` always returns "UTF-8" for above files.

**EDIT:**
After i ran the following code i think `mb_convert_encoding()` cant solve my problem:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("mp", FilesystemIterator::UNIX_PATHS));
$iterator = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/^.+\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/i', RegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

foreach ($iterator as $file)
{
    foreach (mb_list_encodings() as $encoding)
        var_dump(rawurlencode(mb_convert_encoding($file[0], "UTF-8", $encoding)) . " : " . $encoding);
}
```

I guess this is something about encoding but i don't know how to do.

Comment: mb_detect_encoding() isn't omniscient and will fail frequently, just because it's almost impossible to tell for sure what encoding a chunk of text uses.

Answer (score 1):

So, the main thing is that most transports (network, files, rpc) will want characters that are a byte at most. The URL encoding (%FF) expects input data to be a byte per character also.

So what you need to do is utilize UTF8. It will take multi-byte characters and make a string of 1 byte characters out of it. From this string, you can do things normally ascii could do.

What you want to do is explicitly set encoding for php:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

Now all of your internal strings and filenames etc. will be UTF-8 (single byte) encoded. 
From here you can echo out the filename AS-IS and it will hit the transport as encoded data. From javascript, all you have to do is send a request using AJAX, and it will all be neatly decoded for you automatically, ready to use in the browser :) Just make sure you set your content-type in your html file, as this will be used as your default JS encoding.

```
<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=utf-8″ />
```

Comment: If i use `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` on top of code still getting wrong encoding `rawurlencode(mb_convert_encoding($file[0], "UTF-8"));` (e.g. still Russian characters encoded as %3F(?))

Comment: you shouldnt have to use mb_convert_encoding($file[0], "UTF-8"), or even rawurlencoding if youre just echoing the data back (php will make all strings UTF-8 by default

Comment: I didnt use them at first, but i got weird characters when i just echoing filenames. Html file encoding is UTF-8 without bom and content type is utf-8 too. Only solution i found is the above one: `rawurlencode(mb_convert_encoding($file, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-9"))` but this only works for Turkish characters, because "ISO-8859-9" is for Turkish: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-9